# Android JNI crashes using BreakPad

Tags: android, android-ndk, obfuscation, dexguard, google-breakpad

I am using Breakpad for catching NDK crashes and it is integrated with HockeyApp. Everything works fine except for release build where is used code obfuscation with DexGuard. So basically stacktrace is unreadable in this case.

Did anyone had a similar problem with this configuration, or there is some other potential solution for NDK crashes log where DexGuard is included so it can be shown on Hockeyapp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you applying the encryption feature for native libraries?

Comment: Yes, it is applied.

Comment: Dexguard 6.x has problem with native lib encryption on some devices and also class encryption may cause some problems, not sure about your dexguard version. Just try to play around with adding/removing some of the encryption configurations.

Comment: I uploaded mapping.txt which is generated by DexGuard and Symbols.zip (which contains all .so files). As I said this is working perfectly if the dexguard encryption is not applied on .so files otherwise stacktraces are just not human readable for native crashes.